# NUNit - .xml resources and "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

Tags: xml, nunit

In my C# project I use .xml files, but the problem occurs with the NUnit. If I try to add the files as a resources to the project, after running the unit tests there is an error in most of the them:
"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".

When I try to hardcode the relative path to the files, the program runs fine, but some of the tests fail, showing the error:
"System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path „C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs14_001\XmlFiles\MyFile.xml”"

I'm using the latest NUnit 3.2.0.

Comment: Do you access the resources from OneTimeSetUp as well as the test itself? It's likely that the two are running on different threads.

Comment: I'm using [Setup]. Anyway, you were right - it turns out that NUnit was running in other thread than the UI and in the cose there was some updates to the interface, The solution was adding a static variable (set in the Setup) that would prevent from updating the UI when the tests are running. Now every test has passed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that NUnit was running in other thread than the UI and in the code there was some updates to the interface. The solution was adding a static variable (set in the Setup) that would prevent from updating the UI when the tests are running. Now everything is fine - problem solved.